# Symfony embedded ChoiceType form updating every entity instance

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I have an `EditAnnouncementType` form which is embedded in a `CollectionType` form. The embedded form has two `ChoiceType` forms, one which properly updates the mapped `Announcement` entity. The other one however, will attempt to update all instances of the entity in my database, resulting in this error.

> Type error: Argument 1 passed to AppBundle\Entity\Announcement::setType() must be of the type integer, null given, called in /Users/dperezpe/dev/grand-central/673/grand-central/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/PropertyAccess/PropertyAccessor.php on line 528

**EditAnnouncementType.php** The `type` form is the error one.

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('edit', SubmitType::class,
            array
            (
                'label' => 'Save changes',
                'attr' => ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']

            ))

        ->add('type', ChoiceType::class,
            [
                'choices' =>
                    [
                    'info_type' => 1,
                    'star_type' => 2,
                    'alert_type' => 3,
                    'lightbulb_type' => 4,
                    'event_type' => 5,
                    'statement_type' => 6,
                    'cat_type' => 7,
                    'hands_type' => 8
                ],
                'expanded' => true,
                'multiple' => false,
                'required' => true,
                'label_attr' => array(
                    'class' => 'sr-only'
                ),
            ])


          ->add('audience', ChoiceType::class,
              [
                  'choices' =>
                      [
                          'Students: anybody with a student level field populated' => 'students',
                          'Employees: anybody with an employee ID number' => 'employees'
                      ],
                  'expanded' => true,
                  'required' => true,
                  'multiple' => true
                      ])
```

**The CollectionType**

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('announcements', CollectionType::class,
        [
            'entry_type' => EditAnnouncementType::class,
            'entry_options' => ['label' => false],
        ]);
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'data_class' => AnnouncementManager::class
    ]);
}
```

I suspect it is related to the difference in the HTML name that was rendered to this, where the type inputs are missing an empty `[]`

```
<input type="radio" 
id="announcement_edit_collection_announcements_221_type_0" 
name="announcement_edit_collection[announcements][221][type]" 
required="required" value="1">


<input type="checkbox" id="announcement_edit_collection_announcements_221_audience_0"
 name="announcement_edit_collection[announcements][221][audience][]
"value="students">
```

Comment: The `type`  input misses empty `[]` because it doesn't allow multiple values (option `'multiple' => false,`. So that's not the case.

Comment: it seems as though its an issue with my entity `type` field. As I switched the names for the two ChoiceType forms, and the same error throws

Comment: You shouldn't change the name manually but enable the `multiple` option instead if you want to allow multiple values.

Comment: @xabbuh that was just to make sure it wasn't my form that was causing the error.

Comment: @xabbuh I don't want to enable multiple values, I just want to update that single entity the form should be mapped to